# ¿Hay alguna forma de obtener la información del informe de originalidad a través de la API del Classroom de google?

Tags: rest

Vi que existe un informe de originalidad creado a través de Google Classroom para que los profesores puedan obtener un informe del plagio que tienen archivos enviados por estudiantes. ¿Hay alguna forma de obtener esta información a través de la API de Google Classroom?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Por favor has el [tour] y lee [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Eso es algo que deberías consultar en la documentación de Google Classroom.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Informe de Originalidad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/495788/informe-de-originalidad)